# Set Focus to input field

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to set the focus to the searchbar of this [Leaflet Plugin](https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch) input field, but it does not work. I've tried using the following:

```
//jquery  
$("#leaflet-control-geosearch-qry").focus();  
//html  
document.getElementById("leaflet-control-geosearch-qry").focus();
```

You can try it out by yourself. The focus won't be set to set searchbar by using the above mentioned lines.

Mapping one of these to a button and clicking on the button will set the focus to the searchbar.

```
<script>
    //Set Focus to Search Box
    function setFocusToSearchBar(){
        document.getElementById("leaflet-control-geosearch-qry").focus();
        //or $("#leaflet-control-geosearch-qry").focus();  
    }
</script>


<div id="Focus_on_Searchbar">
    <button id="sidebar_button_focus" onclick="setFocusToSearchBar();">
        Focus on Searchbar
    </button>
</div>
```

This works! 
Using one of these with the Chrome/FF Console won't work and I have no idea why not because it works with a button.?

Any ideas?
I'm using Bootstrap for my Header-Bar...maybe this is important?

Comment: Have you tried using `autofocus` directly on on the html field? i.e. `<input type="text" autofocus>`. Never mind, Just saw you updated the question a bit...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works. What's happening is that when your console is open, *the console has the focus*.

Type this on the console:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("leaflet-control-geosearch-qry").focus();
}, 5000);  //Will deffer execution 5 seconds
```

Then close the console. After 5 seconds, it will focus.
So, it's not a coding problem, don't worry ;)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for this tip. It's working now. Even the code-snippets from my initial post are working.  After closing the console, the focus is set to the search bar. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my "bigger problem". I'm working on a project, where a leaflet map should be controlled via speech. I'm using the Google WebSpeech API and I want to trigger the event by a command like "Search" and the focus should be set to the search-bar. I've thought that this might be the same problem, but the map is definitely the active window.

Comment: Of course :) I've simply forgotten to click the tick. Should I open a new question for the WebSpeech stuff/problem?

Comment: @schlomm what's the bigger problem you have? I don't understand it well

Comment: It's better if you open a new question so other people can help you besides me ;)

Comment: Done ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082080/set-focus-by-using-webspeech-api

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, maybe the DOM is not ready yet when you try to set the focus. Did you encapsulate your code with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    …
    $("#leaflet-control-geosearch-qry").focus();
    …
});
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#leaflet-control-geosearch-qry').attr('tabIndex', -1).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one simply worked for me inside js function within my html page.

```
<script language="javascript">
function PopulateVal() {
// some other stuff 
document.getElementById("fname").focus();
}
</script>
```